# Opencv plus unity (Assets store plugin )

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine

I need to find the "ConvexityDefects" using the ConvexHull As of now below is my code using "https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/opencv-plus-unity-85928"   unity plugin

Currently I am not able to pass a Point Array to "ConvexityDefects" function as it is accepting the second parameter as integer [] and not able to convert the Point to Integer array.

Error I am getting is "error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'OpenCvSharp.Point[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
"

```
          Point[] hull;
          Point[][] contours;
          for (int i = 0; i < contours.Length; i++)
          {


           hull =  Cv2.ConvexHull(contours[i], false);
           defects =  Cv2.ConvexityDefects(contours[i], hull);
               Cv2.DrawContours(frame, new Point[][] { hull }, (int)largestContour, new OpenCvSharp.Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a point and an int are different, so a point array and an int array are just as different.

OpenCV often uses InputArray to transfer large amounts of data to the GPU. You need to create an input array using its Create method and the contour array of your choice. If you want to optimize your code, you may want to reuse the same array for each contour, but that's up to you.

Comment: Hi @Louis Garczynski
We tried creating the inputarray using its Create method but its not working, Below is the code
   //  InputArray.Create
            for (int i = 0; i < contours.Length; i++)
            {
               
               hull =  Cv2.ConvexHull(contours[i], false);
        
                for (int k = 0; k < hull.Length; k++)
                {
                    Debug.Log("jihjib" + hull[k]);

                    defects = Cv2.ConvexityDefects(contours[i], InputArray.Create(hull) );
                   
                }
             }

Comment: Can you format your code correctly and provide the error message?

Comment: error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'OpenCvSharp.InputArray' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'

Above is the error message

Comment: It appears that your particular adaptation of OpenCV sharp doesn't use InputArrays, but creates them. I would try to "flatten" your array, which means your array should contain all the x points in even positions, and all the y points in odd positions.

Comment: You should be able to do this with linq, with something like `Cv2.ConvexityDefects(contours[i], hull.SelectMany(p => new []{p.x, p.y}))`

Comment: I tried you solution and received the following error
"OpenCVException: 0 <= hcurr && hcurr < npoints
OpenCvSharp.NativeMethods+<>c.<.cctor>b__1286_0 (OpenCvSharp.ErrorCode status, System.String funcName, System.String errMsg, System.String fileName, System.Int32 line, System.IntPtr userdata) (at Assets/OpenCV+Unity/Assets/Scripts/OpenCvSharp/PInvoke/NativeMethods.cs:190)
OpenCvSharp.Cv2.ConvexityDefects (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] contour, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] convexHull) (at Assets/OpenCV+Unity/Assets/Scripts/OpenCvSharp/Cv2/Cv2_imgproc.cs:3319)
"

Comment: Honestly, I can't really help you more. I'd suggest contacting the creators of the package you use, because if this is the only possible of ConvexHull, and if it only takes ints, and if you can't just send points in a flattened array, I am utterly lost.

Answer (score 0):

@Louis Garczynski below is the formated code

```
    Point[][] contours;
    Point[]  hull;
   for (int i = 0; i < contours.Length; i++)
    {
      hull = Cv2.ConvexHull(contours[i], false);
      for (int k = 0; k < hull.Length; k++) 
        {
             Debug.Log("jihjib" + hull[k]); 
            defects = Cv2.ConvexityDefects(contours[i], InputArray.Create(hull) ); 
        }
    }
```